# Regarding Phd in distance learning mode

Tags: phd, distance-learning

I hold a bachelors in Engineering from an Indian university and have six years of work experience in the software industry. Is there any foreign university that offers a PhD related to finance in distance learning mode?

Comment: [Sure there are.](https://www.google.com/#q=%2B%22distance+learning+programs%22++%2Beconomics+%2BPhD)

Comment: @J.R.: Heh. The top hit is an MIT web page saying "we do not offer a distance learning degree".

Comment: @Nate - I wasn't sure if this was even on-topic. Moreover, I'd be surprised if every hit was a "we do not offer..." hit.

Comment: @J.R.: I know, I just thought it was funny.

Comment: @J.R. - Even I am seeking answer for the same question, I did M.Phill(Comp.Sc.) from a reputed Indian University and got job in a Software Company, now I want to go for Ph.D(Comp.Sc.), if I will go for this  http://www.open.ac.uk or any foreign university then how I can get the things done, are these online courses and if I completed is this degree approved in India by UGC.

Sorry for length comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, most PhDs can probably be (largely) conducted at distance. I live quite a way from the University at which I'm registered for my psychology PhD. However, you might want to try contacting the Open University http://www.open.ac.uk which is the UK's very highly regarded distance learning University. They do offer PhDs and I would assume that since they are geared up for distance work they might be one of your best options.